# function to return the highest count value using a rule

Tags: python, pandas

I have  two columns like shown below, and trying to return the highest count of the second column, but its just returning me the highest count on rating without considering the gender

DATA :

print (df)

```
   AGE GENDER rating
0   10      M     PG
1   10      M      R
2   10      M      R
3    4      F   PG13
4    4      F   PG13
```

CODE :

```
 s = (df.groupby(['AGE', 'GENDER'])['rating']
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))
       .rename_axis(('a','b', 'c'))
       .reset_index(level=2)['c'])
```

OUTPUT :

```
print (s[F])
('PG')

print(s[M]

('PG', 'R')
```

Comment: I dont see a question here

Comment: What is your question

Comment: I am not able to return the highest rating for male and female separately

Comment: update your question

Comment: Thanks I did it @espoir

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need for counts with categories and ratings use [`groupby`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.groupby.html) + [`value_counts`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.value_counts.html) + [`head`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.Series.head.html):

```
df1 = (df.groupby('gender')['rating']
         .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(1))
         .rename_axis(('gender','rating'))
         .reset_index(name='val'))
print (df1)
  gender rating  val
0      F   PG13    2
1      M      R    2
```

If want only top ratings seelct first value of index per group:

```
s = df.groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])
print (s)
gender
F    PG13
M       R
Name: rating, dtype: object

print (s['M'])
R
print (s['F'])
PG13
```

Or only top counts select first value of `Series` per group:

```
s = df.groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().iat[0])
print (s)
gender
F    2
M    2
Name: rating, dtype: int64

print (s['M'])
2
print (s['F'])
2
```

EDIT:

```
s = df.groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])

def gen_mpaa(gender):
    return s[gender]

print (gen_mpaa('M'))

print (gen_mpaa('F'))
```

EDIT:

Solution if `genre id` values are strings:

```
print (type(df.loc[0, 'genre id']))
<class 'str'>

df = df.set_index('gender')['genre id'].str.split(',', expand=True).stack()
print (df)
gender   
M       0    11
        1    22
        2    33
        0    22
        1    44
        2    55
        0    33
        1    44
        2    55
F       0    11
        1    22
        0    22
        1    55
        0    55
        1    44
dtype: object

d = df.groupby(level=0).apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]).to_dict()
print (d)
{'M': '55', 'F': '55'}
```

EDIT1:

```
print (df)
   AGE GENDER rating
0   10      M     PG
1   10      M      R
2   10      M      R
3    4      F   PG13
4    4      F   PG13

s = (df.groupby(['AGE', 'GENDER'])['rating']
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))
       .rename_axis(('a','b', 'c'))
       .reset_index(level=2)['c'])
print (s)

a   b
4   F    PG13
10  M       R
    M      PG
Name: c, dtype: object
```

Comment: when I insert this " s = df.groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0]) " and returning s... its throwing me an error. I just need to send gender as my input for the function and it should give me the most frequent rating directly

Comment: its just giving me the rating as same for both the genders, like F- pg13 and M -PG13

Comment: Hmm, maybe same number of top, you can check it by `print(df.groupby('gender')['rating'].value_counts())`

Comment: This is my input gen_mpaa('F') , the out put is 
GENDERCODE
F    PG13
M    PG13
U    PG13

Comment: ok, but it should just return the rating of 'F' when given 'F' as my input

Comment: I am a bit confused, what is problem? Wrong output - wrong returned strings? Or cannot return only one string?

Comment: when I input for only 'F' it should just return me the  highest count rating of 'F'

Comment: OK, what is expected output?

Comment: input : gen_mpa('F'), output : PG13

Comment: here we are returning s[gender], what if I want to return multiple parameters ? I have age_range as another parameter for my function gen_mpaa, and I want to return that as well. How do I do it?

Comment: Hmmm, I am now a bit confused. You unaccept my solution so the best is ask this `pylang`. Also the best is modify solution with input data and expected output.

Comment: hey I got it, I just used s[gender][age_range]

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/164809/discussion-between-pylearner-and-jezrael).

Comment: hey @jezrael .. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719674/how-to-use-different-combinations-of-group-by-while-trying-to-get-the-top-most-v ....can you answer this ?

Comment: I can check it.

Comment: Thanks, will be waiting for your reply

Comment: hey you mentioned this in the above code **s = df.groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])** what if I give a specific value to the gender say `s = df.groupby('MALE')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])` its throwing me an error ... what to do incase of that ?

Comment: it just says **KeyError: 'MALE'**

Comment: It means there is no column `MALE`. if need filter values in `gender` by `MALE` need `s = df.query("gender == 'MALE'").groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])`

Comment: in that case if i have multiple groupby's,  **s = df.groupby(['MALE','YOUNG])['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])**

Comment: then change `df.query("gender" == 'MALE')` to `df[df["gender"].isin(['MALE','YOUNG'])]`

Comment: hey can you look at this, I have briefly mentioned it. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48741867/how-to-use-columns-values-to-groupby

Comment: Am using this code **s = df.groupby(['MALE', 'GENDER'])['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().index[0])** to get the top most frequent as my index is 0. As I need 2nd top most also, I have set the index to 1. But in my data I dont have the second top most frequent  It throwed me an error. how to handle it ?

Comment: What do you need happen if no second top? Add `NaN`? Can you explain more?

Comment: It  should only return me the top most, but not error

Comment: I dont understand, do you need instaed top2 if not exist return top1?

Comment: I need outputs for both, but when there is only top 1 and not top2, it should return only top 1

Comment: You need `s = df.groupby('gender')['rating'].apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2)).rename_axis(('a','b')).reset_index(level=1)['b']`

Comment: am doing a group by using ** age and gender**, say I have combinations of ** male and young ** ,  and that combination has only one rating  pg13, so it should only return me pg13, as there is no top 2

Comment: Jez, I guess this will solve my problem,  instead of this **10  M       R
    M      PG** as my output, cant it return `R and PG` if top 1 and top2 are there, and `PG` if only top1 is there,  --- ('R', 'PG') if two, ('PG') if only top1

Comment: And yes your edit is working ... just need the output as explained above

Comment: Can you add expected output to question? Because bad formating of comments. Thanks.

Comment: jez, you can checkout my output in the question. I have edited it accordingly

Comment: I dont understand why for `F` is no second value.

Comment: As my dataset has only one top most for that sequence . Is there a way to get that ?

Comment: Yes, it is possible get top. Why I dont understand why is for `F` not output `('PG', 'NR')`

Comment: The output I mentioned is for the dataset, you used in edit 1, and not my dataset

Comment: I think output from your dataset.

Comment: Ok, you can use your dataset and get me the ouput I expected to be

Comment: No, I dont understand what you need. :( Why is not `('PG', 'NR')` for `F`.

Comment: @pylearner - Can you create new question? Because now answers are different as question :(

Comment: sure, in a min.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48768632/printing-the-top-2-of-frequently-occurred-values-of-the-target-column

Comment: can you check that

Answer (score 2):

Here is a standard library solution for this file:

```
%%file "test.txt"
gender  rating
M   PG
M   R
F   NR
M   R
F   PG13
F   PG13
```

**Given**

```
import collections as ct


def read_file(fname):
    with open(fname, "r") as f:
        header = next(f)
        for line in f:
            gender, rating = line.strip().split()
            yield gender, rating
```

**Code**

```
filename = "test.txt"

dd = ct.defaultdict(ct.Counter)
for k, v in sorted(read_file(filename), key=lambda x: x[0]):
    dd[k][v] += 1 

{k: v.most_common(1) for k, v in dd.items()}
# {'F': [('PG13', 2)], 'M': [('R', 2)]}
```

---

**Details**

Each line of the file is parse and added to a `defaultdict`.  The keys are genders, but the values are `Counter` objects for each rating per gender.  `Counter.most_common()` is called to retrieve the top occurrences.

Since the data is grouped by gender, you can explore more information.  For example, unique ratings of each gender:

```
{k: set(v.elements()) for k, v in dd.items()}
# {'F': {'NR', 'PG13'}, 'M': {'PG', 'R'}}
```

Comment: hey what if I have an additional column say age_range which have values like, 'young', 'adult', so i want the top most from young and male in a combination.

Comment: This code would have to be modified to handle extra columns.  If you post a new question, I could address it.  I will leave this answer as is.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48719674/how-to-use-different-combinations-of-group-by-while-trying-to-get-the-top-most-v ...can you look in here