# printing the top 2 of frequently occurred values of the target column

Tags: python, pandas, pandas-groupby

I have  three columns like shown below, and trying to return top1 and top2 highest count of the third column. I want this output to be generated as shown in the **expected output** .
DATA :

print (df)

```
   AGE GENDER rating
0   10      M     PG
1   10      M      R
2   10      M      R
3    4      F   PG13
4    4      F   PG13
```

CODE :

```
 s = (df.groupby(['AGE', 'GENDER'])['rating']
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))
       .rename_axis(('a','b', 'c'))
       .reset_index(level=2)['c'])
```

output :

```
print (s)

a   b
4   F    PG13
10  M       R
    M      PG
Name: c, dtype: object
```

EXPECTED OUTPUT :

```
print (s[F])
('PG13')

print(s[M])

('PG13', 'R')
```

Comment: Is in output `PG13` ?

Comment: Yes, Thanks I have edited

Comment: and instead `('PG13', 'R')` is `('PG', 'R')` ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you need:

```
s = (df.groupby(['AGE', 'GENDER'])['rating']
       .apply(lambda x: x.value_counts().head(2))
       .rename_axis(('a','b', 'c'))
       .reset_index()
       .groupby('b')['c']
       .apply(list)
       .to_dict()
       )
print (s)
{'M': ['R', 'PG'], 'F': ['PG13']}
```

Comment: Awesome it worked ...You saved me again . Is there any other way that I can greet you ?? I would do it :) Thanks alot.

Comment: You are welcome! Btw, this [solution](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48724663/2901002) does not work?

Comment: No jezz, I have 15 columns which I should do a group by and my sequence combination changes, also, there are null values which it should handle .. i had to ignore them and chnage my sequence again. so the above solution worked . I have created conditions and inserted your code there.

Comment: how can I connect you through linked in or any social networking ?

Comment: I dont use fb, nor something similar. But you can send me email, but not very often check it. ;) Email is in my profile.